# How to get Profile picture,primary e-mail,Facebook link of a user from an android App in Facebook SDK 4.5?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I am using latest Facebook sdk for android in my applicaton.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static CallbackManager callbackmanager;
    private AccessTokenTracker mTokenTracker;
    private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;
    Button fb_login;

    private boolean fb_signincllicked = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        fb_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
        fb_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onFblogin(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onFblogin(boolean fb_btn) {

        fb_signincllicked = fb_btn;

        callbackmanager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
//        setupTokenTracker();
//        setupProfileTracker();
//        mTokenTracker.startTracking();
//        mProfileTracker.startTracking();
        // Set permissions
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackmanager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
//                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
//                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                final Set<String> deniedPermissions = loginResult.getRecentlyDeniedPermissions();

                GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {

                        if (response.getError() != null) {
                            // handle error
                        } else {
                            try {

//                                if (deniedPermissions.contains("email")) {
//                                    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(Login_Activity.this, Arrays.asList("email"));
//                                }

                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                                if (jsonObject.has("picture")) {
                                    String profilePicUrl = jsonObject.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                                    System.out.println("111015:profilePicUrl" + profilePicUrl);

                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("111015:profilePicUrl" + "No Data");

                                }
                                jsonObject.put("full_name", json.getString("name"));
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json.get("id").toString() + json.getString("name"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                jsonObject.put("device_id", Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID));
                                jsonObject.put("fb_id", json.getString("id"));
                                jsonObject.put("signuptype", "1");

                                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Profile.class);
                                i.putExtra("prof_name", json.getString("name"));
                                i.putExtra("fb_id", json.getString("id"));

                                startActivity(i);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d("Cancel", "On cancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d("Error", error.toString());
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (fb_signincllicked) {
            callbackmanager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }


    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
//        mTokenTracker.stopTracking();
//        mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
    }
//    private void setupTokenTracker() {
//        mTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
//            @Override
//            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
//                Log.d("VIVZ", "" + currentAccessToken);
//            }
//        };
//    }
//
//    private void setupProfileTracker() {
//        mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
//            @Override
//            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
//                Log.d("VIVZ", "" + currentProfile);
//            }
//        };
//    }
}
```

After success full login(which succeeded) i want to go to another activity.There i want to show the following,

1. Facebook profile picture in a custom image view(not in the image
   view which Facebook provided).
2. Primary-Email
3. Phone Number(If user provided in Face Book)
4. Facebook link of the user.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On your **onActivityCreated()** put this code :

```
 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    updateWithToken(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());
}
```

then here is my code which i'm currently  using it to make facebook login :

```
private void updateWithToken(AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

    mTokenTracker.startTracking();
    mProfileTracker.startTracking();

    if (currentAccessToken != null) {

        String accessToken = currentAccessToken
                .getToken();
        Log.i("accessToken", accessToken);

        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                currentAccessToken,
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
                                            GraphResponse response) {

                        Log.i("LoginActivity",
                                response.toString());
                        try {
                            String id = object.getString("id");
                            try {
                                URL profile_pic = new URL(
                                        "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large");
                                Log.i("profile_pic",
                                        profile_pic + "");

                            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            if (!sessionManagerFacebook.isLoggedIn()) {
                                sessionManagerFacebook.createLoginSession(object.getString("email"), getResources().getConfiguration().locale.toString());
                                if (cameFromQuestionExtra != null && cameFromQuestionExtra.getString("cameFromQuestion").equals("yes")) {

                                    getActivity().setResult(1);
                                    getActivity().finish();
                                }
                                //startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
                            } else {
                                user = sessionManagerFacebook.getUserDetails();
                                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
                            }

                            getActivity().finish();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields",
                "id,name,email,gender");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();


    }


}
```

And on your **second activity** u just have to make new profile variable :

```
Profile  profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
if (profile != null) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, profile.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        loadImages(profile.getProfilePictureUri(120, 120).toString());
        profileName.setText(profile.getName());

        mDrawer.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_myAccount).setVisible(false);
        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
        String email;
        if (extra != null) {
            email = extra.getString("email");
            profileEmail.setText(email);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (sessionManagerFacebook.isLoggedIn()) {
            profileEmail.setText(userFacebook.get(SessionManagerFacebook.KEY_EMAIL));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, userFacebook.get(SessionManagerFacebook.KEY_EMAIL), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Profile/